# Mavn shade plugin with AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, maven-shade-plugin

I’m using the maven shade plugin as below to create a jar for aws lambda

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.shade.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <!-- Suppress module-info.class warning-->
                                <exclude>module-info.class</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
```

As per the documentation, I am supposed to discard the original-xxx.jar.
But is 14MB source code not too big for AWS lambda?
Is there a way to reduce it. I only used AWS core/event/dynamoDB libraries with Jackson

original-artifactName-version.jar = 7KB.
artifactName-version.jar = 14MB

Comment: 50MB is the size limit for an AWS Lambda deployment. 14MB is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If your Lambda gets too big you can use a Lambda Layer to put all the Lambda's dependencies there. In [this article](https://medium.com/@rostyslav.myronenko/aws-sam-for-a-serverless-java-application-505e1d58a737) you can find how to do it.